# Android Unchecked assignment

Tags: android, arraylist, permissions, android-permissions, toarray

I am using location services in my app, and where I am setting the permissions, I have this warning: *Unchecked assignment: 'java.util.ArrayList' to 'java.util.ArrayList*

Code:

```
permissions.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    permissions.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
    permissionsToRequest = findUnAskedPermissions(permissions);
```

The warning comes up on the last line.

I have defined the Arrays like this at the code start:

```
 ArrayList<String> permissions = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> permissionsToRequest= new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> permissionsRejected = new ArrayList<>();
```

Also later in my code, where I ask for the permission (if not allowed by user):

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (permissionsToRequest.size() > 0) {
                requestPermissions(permissionsToRequest.toArray(new String[permissionsToRequest.size()]),
                        ALL_PERMISSIONS_RESULT);
                canGetLocation = false;
            }
        }
```

here the `toArray` causes the warning: *Call to 'toArray()' with pre-sized array argument 'new String[permissionsToRequest.size()]*

Here I can try to replace it with

```
toArray(new String[0])
```

but not sure if it is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `Unchecked assignment: 'java.util.ArrayList' to 'java.util.ArrayList` warning I assume the return value of the `findUnAskedPermissions` method is just `ArrayList` and not `ArrayList<String>` (what it should be).

As for the Array creation, there is an explanation in the [inspection hint of IDEA](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/plugins/InspectionGadgets/src/inspectionDescriptions/ToArrayCallWithZeroLengthArrayArgument.html) why `toArray(new String[0])` is preferred:

> There are two styles to convert a collection to an array: either using
>   a pre-sized array (like **c.toArray(new String[c.size()])**) or
>   using an empty array (like **c.toArray(new String[0])**.
>
> In older Java versions using pre-sized array was recommended, as the
>   reflection call which is necessary to create an array of proper size
>   was quite slow. However since late updates of OpenJDK 6 this call was
>   intrinsified, making the performance of the empty array version the
>   same and sometimes even better, compared to the pre-sized version.
>   Also passing pre-sized array is dangerous for a concurrent or
>   synchronized collection as a data race is possible between the
>   **size** and **toArray** call which may result in extra nulls at
>   the end of the array, if the collection was concurrently shrunk during
>   the operation.

There is an [in-depth analysis](https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/arrays-wisdom-ancients/#_conclusion) of the different ways to create arrays that came to this conclusion:

> toArray(new T[0]) seems faster, safer, and contractually cleaner, and
>   therefore should be the default choice now. Future VM optimizations
>   may close this performance gap for toArray(new T[size]), rendering the
>   current "believed to be optimal" usages on par with an actually
>   optimal one. Further improvements in toArray APIs would follow the
>   same logic as toArray(new T[0]) — the collection itself should create
>   the appropriate storage.

Comment: thank you for explaining! I defined just ArrayList permissionsToRequest; and then used it like permissionsToRequest.toArray(new String[0]). It worked fine.